# Powershell azure ad: delete user from recycle bin

Tags: azure-powershell

With the newer `AzureAD` module for Powershell, I can't find how to delete a user without putting his data in the recycle bin.

What is the newer for the older (MSOLservices):

```
Remove-MsolUser -ObjectId {ObjectId} -RemoveFromRecycleBin -Force
```

?

As a second strategy, how can I purge the recycle bin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Active Directory PowerShell Module Version 2 is in public preview release. You could use [`Remove-​Azure​AD​User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/remove-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0) to delete a Azure AD user.

For now, the function that  permanently removes an Azure AD user is not supported. Based on my experience, the function will come in the future.

You also could use `Remove-MsolUser` to delete a user permanently.

Answer (score 3):

[`Remove-AzureADMSDeletedDirectoryObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/remove-azureadmsdeleteddirectoryobject?view=azureadps-2.0) (AzureAD module) can delete items from Azure AD recycle bin - example below.

```
$user = "firstname.lastname@mydomain.org"
$usertodel = get-azureaduser -ObjectID $user
Remove-AzureADUser -ObjectId $usertodel.ObjectId
Remove-AzureADMSDeletedDirectoryObject -id $usertodel.ObjectId
```

Note: do save the ObjectID of the user to be deleted before actually deleting it, so it can be reused when calling the `Remove-AzureADMSDeletedDirectoryObject` cmdlet. Otherwise, the ObjectID can be retrieved with [`Get-MSOLUser -ReturnDeletedUsers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msoluser?view=azureadps-1.0) (MSOnline module).